# Bad number error with Linux float variable value comparison operator condition

Tags: linux, command-line, sh

I'm trying to test some logic on an Antminer S9 where I get the output of a command and then from that output I grab a specific float value so I can then put this value into a variable and process with some conditional logic to do some checks and such.

I'm still learning Linux shell and bash scripting so I'm far from an expert so I may be overlooking something simple but I cannot get the variable value of `14167.25` to be checked whether or not it is greater than `1` as a simple example. I think it's because this value is set as a string type and it needs to be an `int` and I cannot easily figure it out so I thought I'd ask others for help.

### Command

```
cool=$(/usr/bin/bmminer-api stats | grep -o 'GHS 5s].*' | cut -f2 -d'>')
```

**Note:** This seems to echo the correct value as expected `14167.25` however I get an error on the conditional logic to compare that number with another.

---

> ***My trouble starts here I think...***

### Conditional Command

```
if [ $cool -gt 1 ]; then echo it is greater than 1; fi
```

**The Error:** This gives me an error of `sh: 14167.25: bad number`.

---

**Other things I tried**

I've tried doubling the `[[ $cool -gt 1 ]]` and also using `$($cool)` and `"$cool"` and probably a few other variations for the variable within both double and single square bracket of the if statement and nothing seems to give me the expected result; rookie mistake perhaps!!

I also read over these posts and tried various unsuccessful things I probably shouldn't list:

- [Shell script programming : “bad number” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171362/shell-script-programming-bad-number-error)
- [How to convert string to integer in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268437/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-unix)

  - I thought piping over to [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) would be the way to go here but I fell short with my testing results
- [Error message during the expr command execution: expr: non-integer argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231362/error-message-during-the-expr-command-execution-expr-non-integer-argument)

---

### Other Details

```
uname -sr
Linux 3.14.0-xilinx-ge8a2f71-dirty
```

### "`bmminer-api stats`" Command Output

```
Reply was 'STATUS=S,When=1012053,Code=70,Msg=BMMiner stats,Description=bmminer 1.0.0|BMMiner=2.0.0,Miner=16.8.1.3,CompileTime=Mon Nov 6 17:17:48 CST 2017,Type=Antminer S9|STATS=0,ID=EE50,Elapsed=964517,Calls=0,Wait=0.000000,Max=0.000000,Min=99999999.000000,GHS 5s=14167.25,GHS av=14115.38,miner_count=3,frequency=662,fan_num=2,fan1=0,fan2=0,fan3=5640,fan4=0,fan5=0,fan6=6120,fan7=0,fan8=0,temp_num=3,temp1=0,temp2=0,temp3=0,temp4=0,temp5=0,temp6=64,temp7=61,temp8=65,temp9=0,temp10=0,temp11=0,temp12=0,temp13=0,temp14=0,temp15=0,temp16=0,temp2_1=0,temp2_2=0,temp2_3=0,temp2_4=0,temp2_5=0,temp2_6=74,temp2_7=72,temp2_8=76,temp2_9=0,temp2_10=0,temp2_11=0,temp2_12=0,temp2_13=0,temp2_14=0,temp2_15=0,temp2_16=0,temp3_1=0,temp3_2=0,temp3_3=0,temp3_4=0,temp3_5=0,temp3_6=0,temp3_7=0,temp3_8=0,temp3_9=0,temp3_10=0,temp3_11=0,temp3_12=0,temp3_13=0,temp3_14=0,temp3_15=0,temp3_16=0,freq_avg1=0.00,freq_avg2=0.00,freq_avg3=0.00,freq_avg4=0.00,freq_avg5=0.00,freq_avg6=656.22,freq_avg7=650.38,freq_avg8=656.88,freq_avg9=0.00,freq_avg10=0.00,freq_avg11=0.00,freq_avg12=0.00,freq_avg13=0.00,freq_avg14=0.00,freq_avg15=0.00,freq_avg16=0.00,total_rateideal=14001.40,total_freqavg=654.49,total_acn=189,total_rate=14167.24,chain_rateideal1=0.00,chain_rateideal2=0.00,chain_rateideal3=0.00,chain_rateideal4=0.00,chain_rateideal5=0.00,chain_rateideal6=4666.72,chain_rateideal7=4667.13,chain_rateideal8=4667.54,chain_rateideal9=0.00,chain_rateideal10=0.00,chain_rateideal11=0.00,chain_rateideal12=0.00,chain_rateideal13=0.00,chain_rateideal14=0.00,chain_rateideal15=0.00,chain_rateideal16=0.00,temp_max=65,Device Hardware%=0.0000,no_matching_work=502,chain_acn1=0,chain_acn2=0,chain_acn3=0,chain_acn4=0,chain_acn5=0,chain_acn6=63,chain_acn7=63,chain_acn8=63,chain_acn9=0,chain_acn10=0,chain_acn11=0,chain_acn12=0,chain_acn13=0,chain_acn14=0,chain_acn15=0,chain_acn16=0,chain_acs1=,chain_acs2=,chain_acs3=,chain_acs4=,chain_acs5=,chain_acs6= oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo,chain_acs7= oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo,chain_acs8= oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo,chain_acs9=,chain_acs10=,chain_acs11=,chain_acs12=,chain_acs13=,chain_acs14=,chain_acs15=,chain_acs16=,chain_hw1=0,chain_hw2=0,chain_hw3=0,chain_hw4=0,chain_hw5=0,chain_hw6=192,chain_hw7=152,chain_hw8=155,chain_hw9=0,chain_hw10=0,chain_hw11=0,chain_hw12=0,chain_hw13=0,chain_hw14=0,chain_hw15=0,chain_hw16=0,chain_rate1=,chain_rate2=,chain_rate3=,chain_rate4=,chain_rate5=,chain_rate6=4750.90,chain_rate7=4729.46,chain_rate8=4686.88,chain_rate9=,chain_rate10=,chain_rate11=,chain_rate12=,chain_rate13=,chain_rate14=,chain_rate15=,chain_rate16=,chain_xtime6={X15=1,X37=1,X48=4,X56=1,X57=1},chain_xtime7={},chain_xtime8={X16=4,X38=11},chain_offside_6=0,chain_offside_7=0,chain_offside_8=0,chain_opencore_6=1,chain_opencore_7=1,chain_opencore_8=0,miner_version=16.8.1.3,miner_id=999c7401123b999c|'
[STATUS] =>
(
   [STATUS] => S
   [When] => 1012053
   [Code] => 70
   [Msg] => BMMiner stats
   [Description] => bmminer 1.0.0
)v
[BMMiner2.0.0] =>
(
   [BMMiner] => 2.0.0
   [Miner] => 16.8.1.3
   [CompileTime] => Mon Nov 6 17:17:48 CST 2017
   [Type] => Antminer S9
)
[STATS0] =>
(
   [STATS] => 0
   [ID] => EE50
   [Elapsed] => 964517
   [Calls] => 0
   [Wait] => 0.000000
   [Max] => 0.000000
   [Min] => 99999999.000000
   [GHS 5s] => 14167.25
   [GHS av] => 14115.38
   [miner_count] => 3
   [frequency] => 662
   [fan_num] => 2
   [fan1] => 0
   [fan2] => 0
   [fan3] => 5640
   [fan4] => 0
   [fan5] => 0
   [fan6] => 6120
   [fan7] => 0
   [fan8] => 0
   [temp_num] => 3
   [temp1] => 0
   [temp2] => 0
   [temp3] => 0
   [temp4] => 0
   [temp5] => 0
   [temp6] => 64
   [temp7] => 61
   [temp8] => 65
   [temp9] => 0
   [temp10] => 0
   [temp11] => 0
   [temp12] => 0
   [temp13] => 0
   [temp14] => 0
   [temp15] => 0
   [temp16] => 0
   [temp2_1] => 0
   [temp2_2] => 0
   [temp2_3] => 0
   [temp2_4] => 0
   [temp2_5] => 0
   [temp2_6] => 74
   [temp2_7] => 72
   [temp2_8] => 76
   [temp2_9] => 0
   [temp2_10] => 0
   [temp2_11] => 0
   [temp2_12] => 0
   [temp2_13] => 0
   [temp2_14] => 0
   [temp2_15] => 0
   [temp2_16] => 0
   [temp3_1] => 0
   [temp3_2] => 0
   [temp3_3] => 0
   [temp3_4] => 0
   [temp3_5] => 0
   [temp3_6] => 0
   [temp3_7] => 0
   [temp3_8] => 0
   [temp3_9] => 0
   [temp3_10] => 0
   [temp3_11] => 0
   [temp3_12] => 0
   [temp3_13] => 0
   [temp3_14] => 0
   [temp3_15] => 0
   [temp3_16] => 0
   [freq_avg1] => 0.00
   [freq_avg2] => 0.00
   [freq_avg3] => 0.00
   [freq_avg4] => 0.00
   [freq_avg5] => 0.00
   [freq_avg6] => 656.22
   [freq_avg7] => 650.38
   [freq_avg8] => 656.88
   [freq_avg9] => 0.00
   [freq_avg10] => 0.00
   [freq_avg11] => 0.00
   [freq_avg12] => 0.00
   [freq_avg13] => 0.00
   [freq_avg14] => 0.00
   [freq_avg15] => 0.00
   [freq_avg16] => 0.00
   [total_rateideal] => 14001.40
   [total_freqavg] => 654.49
   [total_acn] => 189
   [total_rate] => 14167.24
   [chain_rateideal1] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal2] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal3] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal4] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal5] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal6] => 4666.72
   [chain_rateideal7] => 4667.13
   [chain_rateideal8] => 4667.54
   [chain_rateideal9] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal10] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal11] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal12] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal13] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal14] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal15] => 0.00
   [chain_rateideal16] => 0.00
   [temp_max] => 65
   [Device Hardware%] => 0.0000
   [no_matching_work] => 502
   [chain_acn1] => 0
   [chain_acn2] => 0
   [chain_acn3] => 0
   [chain_acn4] => 0
   [chain_acn5] => 0
   [chain_acn6] => 63
   [chain_acn7] => 63
   [chain_acn8] => 63
   [chain_acn9] => 0
   [chain_acn10] => 0
   [chain_acn11] => 0
   [chain_acn12] => 0
   [chain_acn13] => 0
   [chain_acn14] => 0
   [chain_acn15] => 0
   [chain_acn16] => 0
   [chain_acs1] =>
   [chain_acs2] =>
   [chain_acs3] =>
   [chain_acs4] =>
   [chain_acs5] =>
   [chain_acs6] =>  oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo
   [chain_acs7] =>  oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo
   [chain_acs8] =>  oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo
   [chain_acs9] =>
   [chain_acs10] =>
   [chain_acs11] =>
   [chain_acs12] =>
   [chain_acs13] =>
   [chain_acs14] =>
   [chain_acs15] =>
   [chain_acs16] =>
   [chain_hw1] => 0
   [chain_hw2] => 0
   [chain_hw3] => 0
   [chain_hw4] => 0
   [chain_hw5] => 0
   [chain_hw6] => 192
   [chain_hw7] => 152
   [chain_hw8] => 155
   [chain_hw9] => 0
   [chain_hw10] => 0
   [chain_hw11] => 0
   [chain_hw12] => 0
   [chain_hw13] => 0
   [chain_hw14] => 0
   [chain_hw15] => 0
   [chain_hw16] => 0
   [chain_rate1] =>
   [chain_rate2] =>
   [chain_rate3] =>
   [chain_rate4] =>
   [chain_rate5] =>
   [chain_rate6] => 4750.90
   [chain_rate7] => 4729.46
   [chain_rate8] => 4686.88
   [chain_rate9] =>
   [chain_rate10] =>
   [chain_rate11] =>
   [chain_rate12] =>
   [chain_rate13] =>
   [chain_rate14] =>
   [chain_rate15] =>
   [chain_rate16] =>
   [chain_xtime6] => {X15=1
   [X37] => 1
   [X48] => 4
   [X56] => 1
   [X57] => 1}
   [chain_xtime7] => {}
   [chain_xtime8] => {X16=4
   [X38] => 11}
   [chain_offside_6] => 0
   [chain_offside_7] => 0
   [chain_offside_8] => 0
   [chain_opencore_6] => 1
   [chain_opencore_7] => 1
   [chain_opencore_8] => 0
   [miner_version] => 16.8.1.3
   [miner_id] => 999c7401123b999c
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the ["How can I calculate with floating point numbers instead of just integers?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) post, the main point is that **"BASH's builtin arithmetic uses integers only"** and you are working with a float data type which BASH cannot perform [comparison operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) against.

**Workaround**

As a workaround such as talked about in the ["Floating Point Comparison in Shell Script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424770/floating-point-comparison-in-shell-script/2424856#2424856) post, you can use [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) to perform the comparison operations of the float data types. You can evaluation it's result of true or false and have the conditional logic process accordingly based on its result.

**Example Logic**

```
if [ "$(echo "$cool > 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "${cool} is greater than 1"
fi
```

Comment: This seems to be what I needed and the thing I was totally overlooking. Of course I'm using a float data type for this operation. This got me going in the right direction for sure.

Comment: Is using the `[ "$(echo "$cool > 1" | bc)" -eq 1 ]` over the `[ $(bc <<<"$cool > 1") -eq 1 ]` syntax purely personal preference that you know of or does the other way have some sort of gotcha or something?

Comment: `<<<` is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism); my change makes it POSIX compliant. The question mentions Bash but not the tags, so I thought it was better to be on the safe side.